# Forward incoming SSH connection if user = git?

Tags: ssh, git, firewalld

I have a CentOS 7 minimal with Firewalld installed and it serves as the firewall / router for the company. Inside the network, we have a git server, let's name it: gitlab-server. I wish to make it reachable from the internet so we can work with our repositories from elsewhere too. We clone repositories via SSH and nothing else is available for secutiry reasons. Now the question is: How can I forward an incoming connection with firewalld to a specific IP address but ONLY IF the user of the SSH is named `git`?

Dumb way:
I want to execute `git clone git@gitlab-server:myuser/myrepository.git` and be able to do it from home. Also I have to push sometimes so I need to execute `git push origin master` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time the SSH connection is initiated, FirewallD has no way of knowing what what the requested user-id is -- it only knows someone is initiating a connection to port 22.

You can get to a similar function by adding a SSH 'ProxyCommand' on the client, referenced at 
https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine:

```
# .ssh/config on hostA:
Host hostC
ProxyCommand ssh hostB -W %h:%p
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If I add the requested lines, ten if I try to SSH from a remote machine, then the command just stalled and not doing anything. I can cancel it with Ctrl+C but it is not moving anywhere. :/

Comment: Here is what I have now:
`Host firewall
        Hostname XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
        ForwardAgent yes

Host gitlab-server
        ProxyCommand ssh firewall -W %h %p
        ForwardAgent yes`

And here is the ouput of a connection try:

`ssh gitlab-server -vvv
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
Bad stdio forwarding specification 'gitlab-server'
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
`

Comment: I think it would be `Host giblab-server ProxyCommannd ssh firewall` and so on.